# How to see all files and folders including hidden when using Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, hidden-files, findfirst

I am using the following code to get a list of files and folders. I cannot seem to get the list to include hidden files and folders.

```
procedure GetAllSubFolders(sPath: String; Listbox: TListbox);
var
  Path: String;
  Rec: TSearchRec;
begin
  try
    Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPath);
    if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if (Rec.Name <> '.') and (Rec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          if (ExtractFileExt(Path + Rec.Name) <> '') And (Directoryexists(Path + Rec.Name + '\') = False) then
          Begin
            Listbox.Items.Add(Path+Rec.Name);
          End;
          GetAllSubFolders(Path + Rec.Name, Listbox);
        end;
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      Showmessage('Err : TForm1.GetAllSubFolders - ' + e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Take a look into the [`FindFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst) function reference, specifically the `Attr` parameter description. You'll surely find the answer there...

Comment: You can use the functionality of IOUtils

Comment: @TLama excelent. Didnt think to look at the "findfirst" part. Just changed it to if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, Rec) and the problem was solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here's a quote from Delphi help:*

> The Attr parameter specifies the special files to include in addition to all normal files. Choose from these file attribute constants when specifying the Attr parameter.

You should use `faDirectory` or `faHidden` or other flags instead of just `faDirectory` and read help on `FindFirst`!